# Saturating a BJT with an open load

Tags: bjt, load, saturation

Is there some drawback in having a BJT transistor saturating without a load?

The scenario is this: BJT is driving a relay, but there is a switch to have the relay always on or off leaving the BJT collector open. In this case there is just the I<sub>b</sub> flowing in the transistor, my worry is that strange situation can damage the BJT or decrease its life duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the base current does not exceed the manufacturer's recommendation this should not be a worry. You should calculate base current when the collector is open circuit. This is likely to be the worst case scenario.

One thing to watch for is the switch open-circuiting the relay - I'm not sure how you plan to do this but it might be a good idea to put a reverse connected diode across the relay. In case you weren't aware - when you open-circuit a conducting relay or coil or inductor you will get a small spark that can damage a transistor. If you are using the collector switch correctly this stops most of the problem but it's still worth the small investment.